# react form onChange to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am fairly new to React.js and just ran into a problem when trying to validate a form. I have the following form field and onChange function:

```
<AvField type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value={scheduleEvent.name} onChange={this.inputChange} className="form-control-sm" required />

inputChange = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   console.log(name, value);
   let scheduleEvent = {...this.state.scheduleEvent};
   console.log(scheduleEvent);
   scheduleEvent[name] = value;
   console.log(scheduleEvent);
   this.setState({scheduleEvent});
   console.log(this.state.scheduleEvent);
}
```

When I type in "a", I get the following console.log outputs:

```
name a //as expected
{name: ""} //as expected
{name: "a"} //as expected
{name: ""} //this.state.scheduleEvent did not get updated
```

Then, if I type in another character, console.log outputs are as follows:

```
name aa //as expected
{name: "a"} //as expected, but for whatever reason it did not get updated on the first invocation of inputChange
{name: "aa"} //as expected
{name: "a"} // did not get updated
```

When I submit the form, however, this.state.scheduleEvent is correct.

I also tried this example linked from the React website: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010 The same issue exists there as well. Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: When you want to see the setState value as soon as or when the state is updated you need add a call back function with setState method this.setState({ a:a, function(){ console.log(a)}}). Then you can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware setState is asynchronous! State updates are sent to a queue that will be pending until processed, therefore there will be a possibility that you will be returned the existing state. To guarantee that we will ALWAYS access the newly updated state, this.setState comes with a second argument that will allow us to chain a callback once state has been updated.

Update your input change function to:

```js
inputChange = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   console.log(name, value);
   let scheduleEvent = {...this.state.scheduleEvent};
   console.log(scheduleEvent);
   scheduleEvent[name] = value;
   console.log(scheduleEvent);
   this.setState({ scheduleEvent }, () => {
       console.log(this.state.scheduleEvent);
   });
}
```